# Create JavaScript event triggers for Google Analytics 4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, articulate-storyline

Articulate Storyline is a software for creating interactive learning courses.
I can execute JavaScript triggers in storyline files to track button clicks with Google Analytics 4.

I added the following code to the button, but it didn't work.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'click', 'Next Button');
```

The code was working fine with the old version of Google Analytics(UA).
Many designers are looking for the answer. We need developer's help. :)
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is covered here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11147304

It looks like you can do

```
<script>
  gtag("event", "publish", {role: "Writer"});
</script>
```

Edit: additional information in the documentation here; https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11403294?hl=en